# Is there a SQL query to 'create' columns from data in another column

Tags: mysql

i need to create 2 additional columns from data in another column in the same table. i have a columns called Role, specifying different roles, e.g. Supervisor, Administrator, etc.
Now i want to create a column for Supervisor and a column for Administrator, where the e.g. ClientName is the same in example attached
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUJmp.png)

```
ClientName  Role             Name
A123        Supervisor       Dave 1
A123        Administrator    Dave 2
Q012        Supervisor       Jane2
Q012        Administrator    Kent3

Select *
From contacts
```

I want to have from the contacts table the following

```
ClientName       Supervisor          Administrator 
A123             Dave1               Dave2
```

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk5Xx.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Try searching [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+pivot) and [conditional aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+conditional+aggregation)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why is the client `Q012` not listed after all?

Answer (score 0):

If you want just data retrieval, without table structure change a simple conditional aggregation will do.

For the given data examples

```
CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  ClientName varchar(10),
  Role varchar(15),
  Name varchar(15)
) ;

insert into contacts values ('A123','Supervisor','Dave1'),
('A123','Administrator','Dave2'), ('Q012','Supervisor','Jane2'),
('Q012','Administrator','Kent3');
```

Query

```
select ClientName,
       max(case when role='Supervisor' then Name end) as Supervisor,
       max(case when role='Administrator' then Name end) as Administrator
from contacts
group by ClientName;
```

Result

```
ClientName  Supervisor  Administrator
   A123       Dave1        Dave2
   Q012       Jane2        Kent3
```

If you want to change the table structure. Use a single transaction to create a temporary table store the data in the temporary table , then change the structure and insert the data back to main table.

I have taken in consideration that you are using InnoDB storage engine.

```
SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES contacts WRITE;
### Create a temporary table to insert the data from the main table
create temporary table temp_myTable (
  ClientName varchar(10),
  Supervisor varchar(15),
  Administrator varchar(15)
  );

##### Insert unique data to the temporary table
insert into temp_myTable 
 select ClientName,
       max(case when role='Supervisor' then Name end) as Supervisor,
       max(case when role='Administrator' then Name end) as Administrator
from contacts
group by ClientName;

##### Delete all data from main table
truncate contacts;

#####Change  contacts structure 
ALTER TABLE contacts 
  drop column Role,
  drop column Name,
  add column Supervisor varchar(15),
  add column Administrator varchar(15);

###### Insert data to the main table
INSERT INTO contacts  SELECT * FROM temp_myTable;

########### Delete the created temprary table
drop temporary table temp_myTable;

COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/H5qWWTpO)

Answer (score -1):

Create two new columns Supervisor and Administrator and run two queries, one to update supervisors like

```
UPDATE table SET supervisor = name where role='supervisor'
```

and second to update admin

```
 UPDATE table SET admin = name where role ='admin'
```